# AVURLAsset Not Loading (.mov file)

Tags: ios, avasset

I am attempting to load a file called output.mov (created on the iPhone) as an `AVURLAsset` using the following code:

```
NSURL *outputURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", NSTemporaryDirectory(), @"output.mov"]];

AVURLAsset *videoAsset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:outputURL options:nil];
```

The file is located in the `tmp` directory of the app. No errors appear, but it seems that the asset is not loaded as no metadata is available (i.e. calling `NSLog(@"%@", [videoAsset commonMetadata])` returns nothing) so I can't do anything with the asset.

I have used the following code to ensure that the resource is reachable via the URL, and it definitely seems to be:

```
if ([outputURL checkResourceIsReachableAndReturnError:&err] == NO)
        NSLog(@"Not reachable!");
```

so I am unsure why the asset is not loading. I have also tried loading the asset using `[AVAsset assetWithURL:]` but that also doesn't work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: That might be so, but it doesn't solve the problem. Using `NSURL *outputURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"output.mov"]];` yields exactly the same problem. I also don't think that's particularly reasonable grounds to down vote this question - the question is perfectly legitimate and valid.

Comment: Did you manage to figure out the issue Skoota?

Answer (score 0):

It might be because of the encoding of your file. For example, if that file was encoded with `Sorenson 3 (SVQ3)` codec you need to modernize media file before passing it to `AVURLAsset`. You could do it using the `QTMovieModernizer` class.