# Why is AVURLAsset Not Loading the File?

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

OK. I have a nasty feeling that this will be met with the gentle chirp of crickets...

I base that on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15447579/avurlasset-not-loading-mov-file) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35532247/avurlasset-not-loading-video-on-documents-folder-even-using-fileurlwithpath).

I'm actually wondering if this is a feature, not a bug, as maybe there's a security issue with loading a movie locally, then playing it. I would think that isn't the case, but maybe. It should be noted that the loaded asset comes from a REST interaction with a server, in which the movie data is actually just a part of a data query response. It is not something that is loaded directly from a video streaming page (it is SSL, though).

I'm pretty green at AV Foundation.

I have the following code:

```
do {
    // We create a path to a unique temporary file to grab the media.
    let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory()).appendingPathComponent(UUID().uuidString)
    // Store the media in the temp file.
    try myData.write(to: url, options: .atomic)
    let options = [AVURLAssetPreferPreciseDurationAndTimingKey: true]
    let asset = AVURLAsset(url: url, options: options)

    if 0 < asset.tracks.count {
        print("YOU GET \(asset.tracks.count) TRACKS!")
    } else {
        print("NO TRACKS FOR YOU!")
    }
} catch let error {
    NSLog("Error Encoding AV Media: %@", error._domain)
}
```

Pretty basic, eh? The "myData" variable contains a MP4 movie (.m4v) that was downloaded. I write it to a temp file, then load that temp file with [AVURLAsset](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avurlasset/1385698-init), just like it says to do.

The problem is that I can never get the dangblammit movie to play. The file is where it's supposed to be. I can fish out the temp file, slap on a '.m4v' extension, and play it in the QT Viewer.

I am quite prepared to accept a slap upside the head, followed by "ya darn eedjut!", but I'd like to know which "M" I should "RTFM".

Comment: Just for the record, the movie is fairly small. Maybe 4MB. It's a tiny, tiny movie, set to play at 240.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be with this line

```
let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory()).appendingPathComponent(UUID().uuidString)
```

You should add the extension for the file.

```
let videoName = UUID().uuidString + ".mp4"
let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory()).appendingPathComponent(videoName)
```

Hope it fix.

Comment: Yup that did it. Damn. That means I need to write a bunch of code to triage the data. Thanks!